# Scale image on width and crop on height with Coil

Tags: android, imageview, coil

I've a ImageView with fixed height (400dp) and variable width (match parent). I'm using Coil to load the content from the web.

I've some images that are landescape and other that are portrait.

I want to always fit the width and crop the height:

[image]

I can't get that.

If I use CenterCrop, the image is cropped on the width if is too large [image]

If I use CenterFit, the image doesn't fit the width if it's too tall
[image]

What's the best way to obtain the desired behaviour?

I tried using all the possible ScaleType, both on the ImageView and the Coil loader.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom `ImageView` like so:

```
class CustomImageView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs) {
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        val width = measuredWidth
        val height = measuredHeight

        if (width > height) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width)
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension(height, height)
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in your layout like this:

```
<com.example.CustomImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

And load the image using Coil to this `CustomImageView`.

Replace `com.example` with your package name.